# Only Key_Tab & ShiftModifier does't work well with PySide

Tags: pyside

**Pre**

I searched other Questions and couldn't find out the solution.

---

I want to execute Tab key and Shift operation simultaneously because I want to add a new performance by pressing tab key.I know the Shiftmodifier enum is good.
But it doesn't work when the key is Tab key.Do you know how to control it?
On the other hand,Controlmodifier works well.

**When I pushed Tab key**

```
tab only
```

**When I pushed Tab & Control Key**

```
tab & Control
```

**When I pushed Any Key except for Tab & Shift Key**

```
print("tab & any key except for tab key")
```

**When I pushed Tab & Shift Key**

No Response... Why?

**Sample Code**

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import sys

class TSEditer(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(TSEditer,self).__init__(parent=None)

    def keyPressEvent(self,event):


        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
            print("tab & control")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier:
            print("tab & shift")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier :
            print("tab & any key except for tab key")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab:
            print("tab only")

        return QtGui.QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self,event)

def main():
    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(15,e)
    ts = TSEditer()
    ts.show()
    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be
`if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backtab:`

i.e. Key_Backtab is combination of Tab and Shift